# View doesn't move up on iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, animation

I use this code to move view up and change it's color when keyboard appears.

```
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, -self.bgImageView.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height*1.4 self.width, self.height);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [self.view setFrame:newFrame];
    self.overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}];
```

It works on all iPhone simulators with both iOS 7.1 and iOS 8, except iPhone 5 with iOS 7. The color changes but the view doesn't move up.

Comment: A note: don't use self inside a block because of it may cause a retain cycle.   For example: `__weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_group_async(_operationsGroup, _operationsQueue, ^
{
[weakSelf doSomething];
} );`

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the `UIView` to enable it for getting animations working:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```